# Enabling the recommendedTypeChecked config causes the linter to lint its config file and error out

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

How do I enable the recommendedTypeChecked config in typescript-eslint?

The config below works for recommended, but when I uncomment ...tseslint.configs.recommendedTypeChecked, I get the error below

```
import eslint from '@eslint/js';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';

export default tseslint.config(
    eslint.configs.recommended,
    // ...tseslint.configs.recommendedTypeChecked,
    {
        languageOptions: {
          parserOptions: {
            parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
            project: true,
          },
        },
        files: ["src/**/*.ts"],
      },
  );
```

ESLint: 8.57.0

> Error: Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/await-thenable':
> You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated.
> You must therefore provide a value for the "parserOptions.project"
> property for @typescript-eslint/parser. Note: detected a parser other
> than @typescript-eslint/parser. Make sure the parser is configured to
> forward "parserOptions.project" to @typescript-eslint/parser.
>
> Occurred while linting /workspaces/eslint-error/eslint.config.js
>
> ```
> at throwError (/workspaces/eslint-error/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils/dist/eslint-utils/getParserServices.js:33:11)
> ```

parserOptions.project is already set. Not sure what the next step is.

I pared-down the package.json to the below. I [pushed a repo](https://github.com/joehoppe/eslint-error) as well

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.16.19",
    "esbuild": "^0.17.3",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5",
    "typescript-eslint": "^7.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "~4.9.5"
  }
}
```

How do I get the linter to stop trying to lint it's own config file?

The only solution I have found is to comment out the files array, and instead pass in a path when linting. How can I specify this in the config file?

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.ts
```

Comment: You'll need to post more information than just that snippet of a config file. The error message is saying you provided a parser other than @typescript-eslint/parser. Is there more to the config file? Are there different versions in your package.json? What does your package lockfile look like? Help us help you :)
(I didn't downvote, just noting why your question isn't answerable as-is)

Comment: @Josh thank you for telling what may be helpful to add. I added some details, and pushed a pared-down repo in which I was able to reproduce the issue

Comment: I don't get that error when running locally. Try deleting your `node_modules/` directory and re-installing? `rm -rf node_modules; npm i`

Comment: I can reproduce the issue by creating a codespace on the repo above. I noticed that the next line in the error message shows that the linter is trying to lint its own config file, and errors out. Inception-like, it doesn't seem to allow me to ignore the config file itself @Josh

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue by creating a codespace on the repo above. You must have some unsaved changes in the codespace or something. Try resetting all Git changes, clearing `node_modules/`, then re-running `npm install`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the error message component about the parser...

> How do I get the linter to stop trying to lint it's own config file?

This is a known common issue when using typed linting. The tl;dr is that type linting relies on TypeScript to generate type info, but if the TypeScript project doesn't include the file, then type info can't be generated for the file.

This is all documented in the [typescript-eslint FAQs](https://typescript-eslint.io/troubleshooting/#i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured-to-run--however-that-tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-file). Your main stable choices are:

- If you don't want to lint the file, use an ESLint ignore
- If you do want to lint the file, but not with type info, use ESLint overrides to either turn off typed linting for the file, or only turn on typed linting for TypeScript files
- If you do want to lint the file *and* with type info, either add `allowJs` to your `tsconfig.json`, or use a separate `tsconfig.eslint.json` with `allowJs` & configure that as your `parserOptions.project`

Comment: The quick start guide references running `npx eslint .`, with a period. Running that in my codespace generates the error. The fix you suggested is one solution. Removing the path/period from the command is a second. Or, when specifying the path, removing the files array from the config file. I couldn't find this error message documented anywhere - hopefully it helps the next person

Comment: Interesting! Could you file an issue on GitHub please? The error message should link to the troubleshooting docs. If it doesn't, that's a bug on us  (source: am a typescript-eslint maintainer)